# Highcharts Yaxis scale not showing

Tags: highcharts

There are two yAxis. My second yAxis scale is not showing.  why?

http://jsfiddle.net/upBs2/2/

```
 {
        "labels": {},
        "opposite": true,
        "min": 0,
        "title": {
            "text": "y2",
            "style": {
                "color": "LightCoral"
            }
        },
        "index": 1
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is showing.  There's no ticks, though, because you haven't plotted any series against it.  On your 2nd series add:

```
        "color": "LightCoral",
        "suffix": "€",
        "tooltip": {
            "valueSuffix": "€"
        },
        "_symbolIndex": 1,
        "yAxis": 1 // ASSIGN series to it
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/upBs2/3/).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `linkedTo` option http://jsfiddle.net/upBs2/4/